# facebook auto post to user wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

Have you notice when you visits some sites, whatever content you access there is posted on your facebook wall automatically. Sites like youtube, myspace, yahoo, socialcam, viddy etc.. All used this kind of script or app.

How did they do it and how can I do one too?

Answer (score 0):

It's called the [Facebook Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). Read up on it first. How you accomplish it would depend on your application's software stack, but there are plenty of libraries and tools available for most platforms.